# How to fix the height of an element to the "fold" height of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, performance, css, internet-explorer

I'm looking for a cross-browser (including IE => 10, 11) and cross-platform method to apply a specific height to an element with `class="fold"`, where `fold` is defined in CSS like so:

```
.fold {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 45px); /* 45px is the height of fixed header on the top */
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Simple enough?, but there is jank!

What I wish to do here is simply apply the height of the fold i.e. the area *above the fold* and just below the fixed header to the element.

See it working here: https://bubbl.in/

The `div` containing the cat_image (background) will occupy the viewport height as expected, except on iOS Safari where the returned height is slightly bigger because it includes height of browser's url bar in it.

---

*The issue(s):*

(i)  <strike>The `.fold` class works fine on desktop Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, Yandex and Edge. It works okay-ish on IE11 but not so well on IE10 (though it does work sometimes on different installations of windows). Is there a way to getting more backwards support (like IE9/IE8) for this?</strike>

JavaScript is fine as long as it is performant.

(ii) The second issue is that the `.fold` class works fine on iOS Safari but is very very janky on iOS Chrome, Firefox and other few browsers like the UC browser from China. I'm sure that juddering is also there on stock Chrome/alternative browsers of Android phones. <strike>Will confirm this in a bit.</strike> *Confirmed.*

Here's my understanding of why it janks on iOS Chrome, for example:

This has something to do with how Chrome & Firefox calculate and return [viewport height](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) [See item number 11 in *known issues*] to the CSS rendering engine. The value of `100vh` increases as the browser goes from normal to fullscreen mode as the user scrolls down a page. Try it on the iPad!

Since the "effective" viewport height increases, the said height of the `.fold` element goes up and the browser has to recalculate layout and repaint multiple times, causing some heavy FSLs on the page.

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent this recalculation of height of the `.fold` element and fix its value to the viewport height when it first rendered? For once, I guess the *known issue* on iOS Safari is a rather desirable feature.

Edit: Demo page inserted on the top.

Comment: Before you consider trying to backpatch this for earlier versions of IE, you may want to check to see if your users will actually use those versions of IE. Ex: This site shows that IE has less than 0.1% support for versions <= IE 8. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp If you really want to fix the code all the way back to IE 5.5-6.0, have fun! Otherwise, ignore all legacy IE versions. Generally, everyone considers <1% to be the legacy threshold. So according to that stats page IE1.0-10.0 can be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too keen on supporting older versions of IE either, but if there is a way then why not?  Second issue pertains to mobile web and is quite critical, and I'm still trying to dig a way to solve it. I did promote the `.fold` element into its own layer to lower overhead that is introduced when the browser animates to fullscreen mode.

Comment: If you get a chance, can you add a couple screenshots? It's hard to sift through the details and imagine what it looks like without opening up all the browsers and testing it manually. May help get some quicker answers.

Comment: Okay, though looking at just the iPad Chrome is enough to get the picture. Will add some screenshots in a bit.